# My Windows machine is not able to start due to DEP program has blocked everything help me

Tags: windows, data-execution-prevention

Its very Urgent as there is a DEMO of my project today and all my data is in my system

My Windows machine is not able to start due to DEP program has blocked everything, help me out.

I am using windows XP service pack 2